# JsonArray to JsonObject

Tags: arrays, json

i don't know what i'm doing wrong here:

```
public void createArchive(ArrayList<String> worklogIssue) throws IOException {
    String id = null;
        int i = 0;

        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(worklogIssue);


        for (i = 0; i < worklogIssue.size(); i++){
            JSONObject json_obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
            id = json_obj.getString("id");
        }
    }
```

i'm getting this error: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

worklogIssue = Arraylist .

Thanks

Comment: Where's your JSON input? The question should be tagged with `Java` as well.

Answer (score 0):

A `String` is not a `JSONObject`. You can get `id` like this:

```
public void createArchive(ArrayList<String> worklogIssue) throws IOException 
{
    String id = null;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < worklogIssue.size(); i++) {
        id = worklogIssue.get(i);
    }
}
```